# Sonarqube Failed to upload report 413

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am running sonarqube using gradle command ./gradlew sonarqube -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonar-server-url.
I am getting error Failed to upload report - HTTP code 413.
Request Entity Too Large.
I am using sonarserver version : Community Edition Version 7.8.
I am running sonar report using gradle command: ./gradlew sonarqube -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonar-server-url
I am getting error Failed to upload report.
Sonarqube server is on oracle cloud (oci) node  and the report file size is 10M.

Comment: I guess this issue is related to configuration in reverse proxy. Could you please check this post out: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/http-code-413-request-entity-too-large-on-upload-report-step-in-build-pipeline/23102 and https://community.sonarsource.com/t/request-entity-too-large/9340

Comment: Yes, updating the nginx configuration helped to resolve the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 413 Request Entity Too Large

I got this when I was using the Nginx server for SonarQube.

### Explanation

A 413 HTTP error code occurs when the size of a client's request exceeds the server's file size limit. This typically happens when a client attempts to upload a large file to a web server, and the server responds with a 413 error to alert the client.

### Solution

**For Nginx servers**

To allow the request size to be up to 20 megabytes, add the following line to your Nginx configuration file:

```
  ...  
  client_max_body_size 20M;  
  ....
```

configuration files should be found in `/etc/nginx/` directory

#### Tips

- I would recommend updating the dedicated configuration file for SonarQube server placed inside `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` folder
- this property can be placed inside the `server {...}` , `http {...}` or, `location{...}` block of the configuration file

Answer (score 1):

2023 Update

If you are using **Kubernetes Ingress** try below:

```
  annotations:
    nginx.org/client-max-body-size: "500m"
```